# Trying to call a function in a for loop and getting unused argument error

Tags: r

```
readStateData <- function() {
  infile <- paste("state",i,".txt",sep="")
  state <- readLines(infile,n=1)
  statedata <- read.table(infile,header=FALSE,sep=",",skip=1,col.names=c("Rank","City","Population"))
  statename <- list(state,statedata)
  statename
}

# Start loop

for(i in 1:50) {
  readStateData()
  # Add function to big.list
  big.list[[i]] <- readStateData(statename)
}
```

The assignment for class is to bring in 50 files, all named state#.txt, get the state via readLines, get the data via read.table, and ultimately put it all into big.list that'll have all of the data through a for loop.

The problem I'm having is calling the function in during the for loop. I get the error:

```
Error in readStateData(statename) : unused argument (statename)
```

I'm either not calling in the function properly or I've written the function wrong. Both are likely.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different issues here.

1. Do not refer inside a function to a variable which is defined outside. It means instead of access an outside the function defined `i` inside the function:

   ```
   i <- 1
   fct <- function() {
     a <- i + 1
     return(a)
   }
   fct()
   ```

   Pass the variable as an argument to the function:

   ```
   i <- 1
   fct <- function(x) {
     a <- x + 1
     return(a)
   }
   fct(i)
   ```
2. In your function the return statement is missing. See point 1 the last command in the functions. Without a return statement the last written variable is on the stack and is "returned" by the function. This is not the clean way to return a value.

Ergo your code should look like this

```
readStateData <- function(x) {
  infile <- paste("state",x,".txt",sep="")
  state <- readLines(infile,n=1)
  statedata <-read.table(infile,header=FALSE,sep=",",skip=1,col.names=c("Rank","City","Population"))
  statename <- list(state,statedata)
  return(statename)
 }

# Start loop

for(i in 1:50) {
  j <- readStateData(i)
  # Add function to big.list
  big.list[[i]] <- j
}
```

If your files are all of the pattern: state[number].txt you can simplify your code to:

```
# Get all files with pattern state*.txt
fls <- dir(pattern='state.*txt')

readStateData <- function(x) {
  state <- readLines(x, n=1)
  statedata <-read.table(x, header=FALSE,sep=",",skip=1,col.names=c("Rank","City","Population"))
  statename <- list(state,statedata)
  return(statename)
 }

# Start loop

for(i in 1:length(fls)) {
  j <- readStateData(fls[i])
  # Add function to big.list
  big.list[[i]] <- j
}
```

Comment: The way you explain the functions make a lot more sense than when my professor explains them. Thank you.

However, when I run your version of the code, I get this error:

Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument

Googling it seems to imply it's reading the file name wrong, but I have it set (via setwd) to the correct directory.

Comment: Now I know what you want to do! I changed the answer. Now it should work!

Comment: You're awesome! Sorry I didn't describe the problem better.